# Submodel does not show properly in LPub3D

Tags: software, instructions, cad, ldraw

I am new to digital LEGO models and building instructions with LPub3D. In order to find my way around submodels I have created this very simple dummy ldraw model:

```
0 FILE new model.ldr
0 Name: new model.ldr
0 Author: Undefined
1 4 10 -24 -90 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3005.dat
1 4 10 -24 10 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3005.dat
1 4 110 -24 -90 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3005.dat
1 4 110 -24 10 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3005.dat
0 STEP
1 4 60 -32 -90 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3666.dat
1 4 60 -32 10 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3666.dat
0 STEP
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 roof.ldr
0 NOFILE 
0 FILE roof.ldr
0 Name: roof.ldr
0 Author: Undefined
1 1 10 -56 -90 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3005.dat
1 1 10 -56 10 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3005.dat
0 STEP
1 1 10 -64 -40 -0 0 -1 0 1 0 1 0 -0 3666.dat
0 Name: roof.ldr
0 Author: Undefined
0 NOFILE
```

It adds some red bricks in two steps and then references a submodel that itself consists of two building steps, too, adding some blue bricks. The file shows alright in LeoCAD, but when I open it in LPub3D it shows the expected building instructions for step 1 and 2, followed by the two steps of the submodel. But then when it should show the result of merging the submodel into the main model it only shows one blue box at some weird place instead of the submodel. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I might not be doing anything wrong after all. If I switch the preferred renderer from native to LDView under Preferences everything looks fine.

Maybe I should mention that I am using LPub3D 2.3.6 under Linux. At least the Linux version seems to be rather buggy. It regularly crashes with a segmentation fault when you try to edit the configuration. So this behavior might be a bug, too.

Comment: I've also found LEGO CAD under Linux to be pretty buggy.  I've been trying to file bug reports and folks are making improvements.

Comment: @chicks LEGO CAD? What is that?

Comment: I've tried a few different programs.  I wasn't trying to refer to just a specific one.